# "Ever" placement in between a particle and a preposition

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis, phrasal-verbs

A line in *[At Middleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_Middleton)* goes:

> Did you read up ever on this bell tower?

This sentence has "ever" inserted inside a particle-prepositional verb, before the preposition and after the particle. It's a curious word order with the placement of "ever", because more commonly the "ever" would follow "you" or appear at the end of the sentence.

A search on Google Books seems to show that this word order is very uncommon with next to zero instances.

Is this an idiosyncrasy? Does this sound natural to anyone? What about other possibilities?

> Did they gang up ever on you?
>
> Do you look forward ever to a class?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's wrong, but it sounds very formal, a bit ostentatious and possibly outdated. My impression is that your final possibility has a higher chance of being correct and natural than the second, although I can't say for what reason.

Comment: It sounds weird to me, it took a few moments to figure out that it was a rearrangement of "Did you ever read up on ..."